# Scans more IPs than asked

Tags: nmap

I am running this command through Zenmap:

```
nmap -T4 -A -v -iR 1000
```

It is the default 'Intense Scan' with 1000 random targets. On almost every scan I run, however, it seems to scan more than 1000 targets. Usually it's only up by 3 or 5, but I've had it scan 1056.

The output begins with,

```
Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org )
NSE: Loaded 138 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
Initiating NSE at 08:48
Completed NSE at 08:48, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 08:48
Completed NSE at 08:48, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating Ping Scan at 08:48
Scanning 1000 hosts
```

which implies that it started correctly scanning 1000 IPs. At the finish of the scan, however:

```
Nmap done: 1056 IP addresses scanned in 14486.68 seconds
Raw packets sent: 252137 (11.381MB) | Rcvd: 387821 (36.462MB)
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: The only possible scenario I can come up with is that is scans a dynamic IP, and then scans it again but it's moved on (I don't know how dynamic IPs work, though).

Comment: Difference between 'hosts' and IPs? A host can have multiple IPs.

Comment: I'm trying to track this through Nmap's source. There must be some discrepancy between `o.numhosts_scanned` and `o.max_ips_to_scan`, but it's late and I'll have to trace it tomorrow. Does this happen with `-sn` instead of `-A`? What's the smallest `-iR` argument you can provide that still shows extra targets scanned? Can you provide debug output? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in Nmap. Thanks for discovering it! Short answer: there was a bug in how we counted how many addresses were already scanned, which I just fixed in r36341.

Longer answer: Nmap runs scans in several phases. The important ones for this bug are host discovery (Ping scanning) and port scanning. Nmap loops over all possible addresses, doing host discovery in large chunks when necessary, and grabbing some number of "up" hosts to do port scanning on in a group. It stops looping over addresses when it has enough targets for a hostgroup or when the addresses run out. For `-iR`, the addresses never run out, so instead we check whether `o.numhosts_scanned` is less than `o.max_ips_to_scan`. That would work except that we don't consider an "up" host "scanned" until after the port scan phase. So there's the potential to check extra addresses. Over a long scan, most of these get counted anyway because they increment `o.numhosts_scanned` after the port scan phase and before the host discovery phase for the next group, but the last hostgroup will have some carry-over. I fixed this by adding an extra loop check to ensure that "up" hosts were added to `o.numhosts_scanned` before checking against `o.max_ips_to_scan` during the discovery phase.

Example debug output from `nmap -iR 2 -p80 -d -n`:

```
Initiating Ping Scan at 15:14
Scanning 2 hosts [2 ports/host]
Completed Ping Scan at 15:14, 1.48s elapsed (2 total hosts)
Overall sending rates: 4.06 packets / s.
```

This shows that we correctly ping-checked 2 addresses.

```
Nmap scan report for 20.240.133.236 [host down, received no-response]
```

One of them was down, so the report is printed immediately. One of them must have been up because we only got one such report.

```
Initiating Ping Scan at 15:14
Scanning 54.28.85.198 [2 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 15:14, 1.48s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Overall sending rates: 2.71 packets / s.
```

Oops! The one "up" target wasn't counted towards the number of scanned hosts, so ping scan thinks it needs to scan one more to be done.

```
Nmap scan report for 54.28.85.198 [host down, received no-response]
```

That one was down. So 2 down hosts and one up.

```
Initiating Connect Scan at 15:14
Scanning 187.142.197.40 [1 port]
Completed Connect Scan at 15:14, 0.06s elapsed (1 total ports)
Overall sending rates: 17.06 packets / s.
Nmap scan report for 187.142.197.40
Host is up, received conn-refused (0.059s latency).
Scanned at 2016-09-29 15:14:26 UTC for 3s
PORT   STATE  SERVICE REASON
80/tcp closed http    conn-refused
Final times for host: srtt: 59196 rttvar: 33779  to: 194312
```

And here's the third one: port 80 was closed.

```
Read from /usr/bin/../share/nmap: nmap-payloads nmap-services.
Nmap done: 3 IP addresses (1 host up) scanned in 3.06 seconds
```

And here's the output showing that 3 IP addresses were scanned, even though I requested only 2.